# NSArray released early

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsarray

I'm having a problem with my iPhone app crashing when I scroll down on a UITableView. I set NSZombieEnabled to YES, and found out that the NSArray I'm using to fill the table is getting dealloced somehow.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize flashsets;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        //Unrelated code removed from this post
        NSString *listofsetsstring = [[NSString alloc]
                                          initWithContentsOfFile:pathtosetsdata
                                          encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding
                                          error:&error];
        flashsets = [listofsetsstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [flashsets count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSLog(@"IndexPath.row = %i", indexPath.row);
    cell.textLabel.text = [flashsets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; <<<< CRASH HERE!!

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I'm getting `message sent to deallocated instance 0x4ebae20` at the bolded line. In my .h I used `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *flashsets;`, I thought the retain part should keep it from deallocating.

How do I keep it from doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is with :

```
flashsets = [listofsetsstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

change it to

```
flashsets = [[listofsetsstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] retain];
```

edit: the retain in property is only used if you use the setter, so it will only work if you use the following line:

```
[self setFlashsets:[listofsetsstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to remember to use [self variablename] in the future.

Answer (score 1):

in you viewDidLoad it should be self.flashsets =  this will insure the accessor method is used to set the value, and thus the 'retain' behaviour you specified on the property definition will be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

```
 flashsets = [listofsetsstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];//it returns autorealesed NsArray.So If you want Longer Use.you should get Owner ship from that array By Alloc or Copy Or Retain.

flashsets = [[listofsetsstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] retain];
or
flashsets = [[listofsetsstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]copy];
or 
flashsets = [[NsArry alloc ] initWithArray:[listofsetsstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but you may want to use the setter and getter methods when referring to flashsets - the retain part of the property doesn't apply (I don't think) when setting the variable directly.